# I don't know how to put the meaning into sentences?

Tags: meaning

When I search the meaning of a word in a book, I can understand it, but sometime it's hard, because some words have different meanings. So after reading and finding the meaning I understand it, but when I try to use it in my own sentence it doesn't make sense.

I don't know to explain it but, how do I understand the many meanings of big words?

Comment: It will come with practice in context. Read and listen to full sentences with the words. (Also practice writing and speaking, they all make things easier as you practice)

Comment: In addition to Mitch and medica's advice, **talk** to native speakers about the words you are learning. Read! Listen! Talk! You're making progress; keep writing! Try the [English Language Learner's site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: Well, as a native English speaker, I do often use the dictionary, but by far the most useful thing (which you appear to already be doing quite well) is reading / listening to the word in as many contexts as possible to help you notice patterns of its use. What words or phrases are usually used alongside it, how common it actually is (because you probably don't want to learn really obscure long words that only authors would recognize), and what people actually intend when they use it. The dictionary is a good place to get a general idea of how to read a word, rather than when to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply listen to lots and lots of (English language) pop music.

Pretty much every song emphasises "memetically" one or more words.

Pop music was one of the primary "weapons" in making English the simplest, most universal linga-franca last century.

Just listen endlessly to anything from the Beatles through about 2000 - and only catchy, hit songs.

(I don't recommend this to boost your mental powers - but it will most quickly get you "inside" English.)